# What does -pe mean with respect to scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, cluster-computing, qsub

I was reading a script to submit a job to a cluster. I saw this line:

```
-pe threaded 8 -R y
```

what does this mean?

Comment: Could you provide us with some context and relevant code sample ? As of now, your question is extremely unclear

Answer (score 1):

You're using [SGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Grid_Engine), where `-pe` specifies a parallel environment, in your case called `threaded`, asking for 8 nodes. It's not related to the shell or bash, it's a switch parsed by the grid engine when submitting your job. Equivalently, you could submit these switches on the command line:

```
qsub -pe threaded 8 -R y job_file
```

So take a look at `man qsub`.